# Windows API to get netstat -s statistics

Tags: c++, windows, api, netstat

I'm searching a windows API that return the same statistics of netstat -s

Comment: Googled.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4173/Windows-netstat-application

Comment: This question is not an opinion: it's asking if there is a Windows API to return netstat statistics. I'm looking for precisely this. Actually, GetExtendedTcpTable is what I need. I was greatly helped by @Johnny Mnemonic's answer which appeared to slip through.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `GetIpStatistics()` function.

See here for more information and example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365959(VS.85).aspx