# How to create a visual 2D volume binary tree chart

Tags: tree, 2d, binary-tree, volume

Looking for pseudo-code for creating a visual representation of a binary tree using 2D volume as data source.

**Task:** Convert an associative array containing **name** and **volume** data to a visual 2D chart that *automatically makes the decision to split volumes* according to how much space is left for each subsequent *area* contained within the list.

**Assumptions:** Aware of root/parent structure. (Can have one root, but multiple large blocks, containing smaller blocks within. Can represent, HD folder structure, for example.)

Example of the resulting chart and associated data:
The visual chart is the proverbial output of the pseudo code that would be required in order to solve this problem.

**Ps:** I couldn't find this elsewhere on StackOverflow. Has anyone done this before?

[image: Output]

The most elegant solution that I have found so far in a real-world application was **WinDirStat**:

[image]

Can anyone come up with pseudo code for something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Which language?
Regardless, you would be hitting the WinAPI
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373088.aspx

If you are not a natural programmer, WinAPI support for low level programming can be less than ideal.

Other than that, it's not to bad.

Here are some other possibilities.
[Windows API to get netstat -s statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707035/windows-api-to-get-netstat-s-statistics)